# How to horizontally scroll in a React Application (ag grid) with UI automation (WebdriverIO /JavaScript)?

Tags: reactjs, selenium-webdriver, automation, ag-grid, webdriver-io

We have a grid application exactly similar to this demo application:
https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php

I want to horizontally/vertically scroll to any element in this demo site.

I have tried below methods:

1. browser.moveTo() : is not working and throwing below error :

stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

2. browser.scroll(1665, 147.12345) : Is not doing anything. Pass the step.
3. browser or element.scrollIntoView() :shows not an existing method. Following error appears:

Property 'scrollIntoView' does not exist on type 'Client> & RawResult'.t

and

Property 'scrollIntoView' does not exist on type 'Client> & RawResult'.t

I am using webdriverio and typescript for UI automation.

wdio version:
"webdriverio": "^4.14.4"

Comment: Have you tried `.scrollIntoView()`?

Comment: Yup.. It didn't do anything.

Comment: @QualityMatters, Did you try https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/moveTo.html?

Comment: Got this error. stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Answer (score 1):

Though none of the existing methods worked, but I solved it by using the "Tab" key. I followed below steps:

1. I click/select the last visible element in the current screen.
2. I press "Tab" key (Single or multiple as needed)

This scrolled the page horizontally(which solved my purpose for now).

Comment: Thanks, at least I was facing the issue with achieving horizontal scrolling on ag grid but your workaround worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use scroll with javascript:

```
browser.execute(function() {
    document.querySelector('yourElementLocator').scrollIntoView()
})
```

Keep in mind that code inside `browser.execute` does not have access to the outer context. So if you want to pass your element inside you will have to specify this argument after executable code:

```
browser.execute(function(){}, selector)
```

https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/execute.html

Comment: This also didn't work. You can check it's not working in this demo site: https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.waitUntil(
  async () => {
    browser.keys(["\ue00F"]);
    return await countryEle.isDisplayedInViewport();
  },
  15000,
  undefined,
  500
);
```

Comment: Vertical scrolling can be done using this function

Comment: Please read "[answer]" and "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.